# PreSelected Ion-checkbox using id given from API side

Tags: javascript, angular, api, ionic-framework, ionic5

I am gone through many solutions!

i have one checkbox in my ionic app. i am use reactive from in this app. i call one api to get list of data of checkbox -

```
 "Result": [
    {
        "Subject_Id": 1
    }
]
```

In this i got one subject id selected from api side.

i share my code -

```
//ts
getSchemeDetail() {
    this.api
      .post(
        this.api.url + "GetStudentList",
        { StudentId: this.Student.StudentId },
        false
      )
      .then((data: any) => {
     
          this.studentForm.patchValue({ 
          sID: data.sub_Id
          });
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.getStudentList();
        }, 1000);
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        this.common.dismissLoading();
      });
  }
  
   getStudentList() {
    this.api
      .post3(
        "subjectid",
        {
          StudentId: this.studentId,
        }, true )
      .then((data: any) => {
        this.SubList = data.Result;
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.studentForm.patchValue({ sID: this.sid });
            if (this.vid == this.SubList) {
              this.isChecked = true;
            } else {
              this.isChecked = false;
            }
          
        }, 100);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("State Error => ", error);
      });
  }
```

and my HTML code is

```
   //Html code
 <div *ngFor="let s of SubList">
           <ion-checkbox color="primary" type="checkbox" formControlName="sID" [(ngModel)]="s.isChecked" >
</div>
```

i am getting all check box checked.

so how can i get only show that selected check box from the API side

Comment: Your `formControlName="sID` and you are patching value with `this.studentForm.patchValue({ 
          sub: data.sub_Id
          });` here, you have two different formControlName. `sub` and `sID` both are not known to each other

Comment: @GaurangDhorda i am explain with other example so its a mistake, now i correct this.

Comment: Can you share data of `SubList` object ? and is `[(ngModel)]="s.isChecked"` here where this `s` come from ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda  {
            "sub_Id": 1,
            "SubName": 'eng,
        }, and s is come from SubList

Comment: is your api gives you `checked : true` for all checkbox ID

Comment: @GaurangDhorda Api provide only one `sub_Id`. Now i need to show its checked and other is not check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232026/discussion-between-pritesh-and-gaurangdhorda).